# Center text on background image

Tags: html, css

I am struggling with positioning text on the vertical and horizantal middle of my background image. My background image is a badge which should always have the same size, my text on top is a number with 1 or 2 digits. All of this together is my heading.

**HTML:**

```
<h1>
  <span class="playerlevel">
    <strong>12</strong>
  </span>
  player
  <span class="playertag"> #tag</span>
</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
.playerlevel strong {
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/IuhiyzQ.png);
  color: #fff;
}

.playertag {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

**How the result should look like:**

[image]

**What my code creates:**

[image]

**JSFiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/nafhLz1w/

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/3kmzh34m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use background-size as cover with some padding

snippet below

```css
.playerlevel strong {
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/IuhiyzQ.png);
  background-size:cover;
  padding:10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.playertag {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span class="playerlevel">
    <strong>12</strong>
  </span>
  player
  <span class="playertag"> #tag</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add 'display: inline-block;' to your css.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were just missing the `display:block;` or `display:inline-block` attribute.

Add it will make the number show up properly on your background image: https://jsfiddle.net/nafhLz1w/1/

Sidenote: I don't however suggest to wrap everything of this in a H1 tag though, that's not a good way to handle that. Rather wrap it in a div or another block element.

Comment: I thought the same but I couldn't figure out a better way to place that image + text right in front of the heading

Comment: You could then have used the display:inline-block element or you probably could also use the background-size:cover property to make that work, as shown below by user: repzero

Comment: Further edits to the background-position and repetition can also be altered by using: https://jsfiddle.net/nafhLz1w/5/

Comment: Yes you can do this by altering the height/width and line-height like so: https://jsfiddle.net/nafhLz1w/7/

Personally I would go around 50px to also fit double digits like so: https://jsfiddle.net/nafhLz1w/8/

Comment: Well one last question about your background-position property. It simply doesn't seem to center the background/front text as intended. You can see it more clearly when you add another digit: https://jsfiddle.net/nafhLz1w/9/

Comment: You're not using my code to be honest, that's why it's not properly centered, if you want three digit you also might want to consider scaling the box up.

Here's my code with a three digit number: https://jsfiddle.net/nafhLz1w/10/

Comment: You can also add some padding to accommodate for larger numbers: https://jsfiddle.net/nafhLz1w/12/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set 2 properties: `background-size: cover;` and a padding e.g. `padding: 10px;`

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hwkkr877/

Comment: doesn't look like a solid solution to me: http://i.imgur.com/puu0FwT.png . Obviously I could just have messed with the values as well until it fits for my example. Also it seems to be repeating on the y axis

Comment: repetition could be disabled by using the background-repeat:no-repeat; property.

Like so: https://jsfiddle.net/nafhLz1w/5/

Answer (score 0):

This will surely work.

```
.playerlevel {
display: inline-block;
}

.playerlevel strong {
 background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/IuhiyzQ.png");
 background-size: contain;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: normal;
 height: 28px;
 line-height: 28px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
 width: 28px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {
    var searchBGDIV = $('#searchBG');
    var backgrounds = new Array(
        'url("https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/background-18.jpg")',
        'url("https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/background-1247931_960_720.jpg")',
        'url("https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/background-pictures-2.jpg")',
        'url("https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/background-wallpapers-26.jpg")'
        );

    var current = 0;

    function nextBackground() {
        searchBGDIV.css('background',
        backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]
        );
        searchBGDIV.css("background-position", "center center");
        searchBGDIV.css("min-height", "400px");
        setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
    }

    setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
    searchBGDIV.css('background', backgrounds[0]);
    searchBGDIV.css("min-height", "400px");
    searchBGDIV.css("background-position", "center center");
});
```

Comment: I'm lookin for someone who can help me how to add text on each and every image